# How to split a string based on word match from different lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-re

I have a string. Now I want to split the string into parts if anything matches from two different lists. how can I do that ? there what i have.

```
dummy_word = "I have a HTML file"
dummy_type = ["HTML","JSON","XML"]
dummy_file_type = ["file","document","paper"]

for e in dummy_type:
    if e in dummy_word:
        type_found = e
        print("type ->" , e)
        dum = dummy_word.split(e)
        complete_dum = "".join(dum)

        for c in dummy_file_type:
            if c in complete_dum:
                then = complete_dum.split("c")
                print("file type ->",then)
```

In the given scenario my expected output is `["I have a", "HTML","file"]`

Comment: What if the string contains multiple `dummy_type` or `dummy_file_type` like `'This HTML file is also an XML document'`, or are you certain this kind of input never occurs?

Comment: The items from those lists should be split individually, The rest should be together. on the given example expected output : `["This" ,"HTML" ,"file" ,"is also an", "XML"," document]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sort of tasks a handled pretty well by [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Here the key will translate to individual words if the words is in the set of words, or `False` if it's not. This allows all the non-special words to group together and each special word to become its own element:

```
from itertools import groupby

dummy_word = "I have a HTML file"
dummy_type = ["HTML","JSON","XML"]
dummy_file_type = ["file","document","paper"]

words = set(dummy_type).union(dummy_file_type)

[" ".join(g) for k, g in 
 groupby(dummy_word.split(), key=lambda word: (word in words) and word)]

# ['I have a', 'HTML', 'file']
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
dummy_word = "I have a HTML file"
dummy_type = ["HTML","JSON","XML"]
dummy_file_type = ["file","document","paper"]

temp = ""
dummy_list = []
for word in dummy_word.split():
    if word in dummy_type or word in dummy_file_type:
        if temp:
            dummy_list.append(temp)
            print(temp, "delete")

        print(temp)
        new_word = word + " "
        dummy_list.append(new_word)
        temp = ""
    else:
        temp += word + " "
    print(temp)
print(dummy_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way using `re`:

```
>>> list(map(str.strip, re.sub("|".join(dummy_type + dummy_file_type), lambda x: "," + x.group(), dummy_word).split(',')))
['I have a', 'HTML', 'file']
>>>
```

First, form a regex pattern by concatenating all the types using `join`. Using `re.sub`, the string is replaced where tokens are prepended with a comma, and then we split the string using comma separator. `map` is used to strip the whitespaces.